# Memory leak when changing values of a C++ vector in a DLL

Tags: c++, memory, vector, dll

I am working on a C# plugin which calls a C++ DLL (with C wrapper in the DLL to do the link). In the C# program, I call several times the same method `callMe` of my DLL. In this method, I change values in a vector `thermogram` to perform others operations later.

Between each call, I try to free the memory because for now, at each call the RAM increase of 18 Mo so it is not good at all. I don't understand why because at each call, I just replace some values in an existing vector (2000 to be precise). So I tried to free the memory in different way (methods from vector class : erase, clear, shrink_to_fit) but nothing change the result. And all forums talk about these previous ways so I don't know what to try more.

C++ method :

```
bool MyClass::callMe(int pixel_value, int iImage)
{
    if (thermogram.size() == 0) {
        thermogram.resize(_nFrame - iFramesPass);
    }
    thermogram[iImage] = (double)pixel_value;
    sizeThermo = iImage;
    return true;
}
```

I also try not to clear between two calls, just to replace values at each new call, but the memory stll increase.

Maybe I miss something about calling a method from a DLL, or just I have a memory leak?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are asking about, but `std::vector` doesn't "leak" memory in the usual sense of the word though it can be stubborn about releasing it's memory when reducing it's size or clearing it (it's usually not allowed to). Try the non-binding [std::vector::shrink_to_fit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) or assigning a default constructed instance to it (`my_vector = {};`).

Comment: But is it normal than even if I don't change the size, or clear the vector, when I change a value in the second call, the memory continue to increase?

Comment: No, if you you don't add elements to an `std::vector` it will not grow. The problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: It is was I understood reading the documentation, thank you for confirming. So I don't understand what my program is not doing this.

Comment: Have you proven within your own environment that this code is responsible for the extra memory use? If this code is commented out, does the memory still go up?

Comment: Good remark. But yes I did this, and the memory don't increase when I comment my line.

Comment: Couldn't you not just compile with ASAN on Linux and trace down, where you are leaking the memory?

Comment: @KavehVahedipour I can't, I am on Windows 7. Sorry

Comment: I understand. I saw that you referred to `DLL`s. Couldn't you just take that part of the code, that you are suspecting and take that to Linux?

Comment: @KavehVahedipour I do know Linux, so I don't sorry. And I can debug the dll if you want me to add some breakpoints.